# Read Bytecode classic asp from URL

Tags: image, asp-classic, bytecode

http://www.jiemai.com/imagesupload/1582/middle/0858-1-001.jpg

I Want to save the above image URL as a file with the name '0858-1-001.jpg' in classic ASP.
I really appreciate if anyone help me. I was trying to use many asp script to read that bytecode.

Comment: Please help me because i have been stuck since last weeek

Comment: Please do not include code in comments, use the edit feature of your question to improve its quality.  Include specifics of what problem you are actually having.

Comment: Thanks Anthony, I got the solution I really appreciate at least you answered me

Comment: If you got it solved either post what you did as new answer and accept it, or delete this question.

Answer (score 2):

Haven't got a server around here but here is the tested vbscript version, to use it in asp you should just have to replace creatObject with Server.CreateObject

```
function download(url, destination)
  download = false
  on error resume next
  set xml = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
  xml.Open "GET", url, False
  xml.Send
  if err.number = 0 then
    if xml.readystate = 4 then
      if xml.status = 200 then 
        wscript.echo xml.readystate
        wscript.echo xml.status
        set oStream = createobject("Adodb.Stream")
        const adTypeBinary = 1,  adSaveCreateOverWrite = 2, adSaveCreateNotExist = 1 
        oStream.type = adTypeBinary
        oStream.open
        oStream.write xml.responseBody
        oStream.saveToFile destination, adSaveCreateOverWrite
        oStream.close
        set oStream = nothing
        download = true
      end if
    end if
  end if
  set xml = Nothing
end function
```